# List all months with a total regardless of null

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a very small SQL table that lists courses attended and the date of attendance. I can use the code below to count the attendees for each month

```
select to_char(DATE_ATTENDED,'YYYY/MM'),
COUNT (*)
FROM TRAINING_COURSE_ATTENDED
WHERE COURSE_ATTENDED = 'Fire Safety'
GROUP BY to_char(DATE_ATTENDED,'YYYY/MM')
ORDER BY to_char(DATE_ATTENDED,'YYYY/MM')
```

This returns a list as expected for each month that has attendees. However I would like to list it as

```
January 2
February 0
March 5
```

How do I show the count results along with the nulls? My table is very basic

```
1234    01-JAN-15   Fire Safety
108 01-JAN-15   Fire Safety
1443    02-DEC-15   Healthcare
1388    03-FEB-15   Emergency
1355    06-MAR-15   Fire Safety
1322    09-SEP-15   Fire Safety
1234    11-DEC-15   Fire Safety
```

I just need to display each month and the total attendees for Fire Safety only. Not used SQL developer for a while so any help appreciated.

Comment: You need a table which has all months. I'd suggest searching for "Calendar table"

Comment: `... right outer join calendar_table ...` (One of the very few cases where I'd recommend right join before left join.)

Answer (score 0):

You would need a calendar table to select a period you want to display. Simplified code would look like this:

```
select to_char(c.Date_dt,'YYYY/MM')
, COUNT (*)

FROM calendar as c
left join TRAINING_COURSE_ATTENDED as tca
 on tca.DATE_ATTENDED = c.Date_dt

WHERE tca.COURSE_ATTENDED = 'Fire Safety'
    and c.Date_dt between [period_start_dt] and [period_end_dt]
GROUP BY to_char(c.Date_dt,'YYYY/MM')
ORDER BY to_char(c.Date_dt,'YYYY/MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Trunc(date_attended, 'MM') Month, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN course_attended = 'Fire Safety' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) Fire_Safety 
FROM   training_course_attended 
GROUP  BY Trunc(date_attended, 'MM') 
ORDER  BY Trunc(date_attended, 'MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own set required year month's on-fly with 0 count and use query as below.

```
Select yrmth,sum(counter) from
(
    select to_char(date_attended,'YYYYMM') yrmth,
           COUNT (1) counter
    From TRAINING_COURSE_ATTENDED Where COURSE_ATTENDED = 'Fire Safety'
    Group By Y to_char(date_attended,'YYYYMM')
    Union All
    Select To_Char(2015||Lpad(Rownum,2,0)),0 from Dual Connect By Rownum <= 12
)
group by yrmth
order by 1
```

If you want to show multiple year's, just change the 2nd query to

```
Select To_Char(Year||Lpad(Month,2,0)) , 0 
From 
(select Rownum Month from  Dual Connect By Rownum <= 12),
(select 2015+Rownum-1 Year from  Dual Connect By Rownum <= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to generate a calendar table inline:

```
with calendar (month_start, month_end) as
     ( select add_months(date '2014-12-01', rownum)
            , add_months(date '2014-12-01', rownum +1) - interval '1' second
       from   dual
       connect by rownum <= 12 )
select to_char(c.month_start,'YYYY/MM') as course_month
     , count(tca.course_attended) as attended
from   calendar c
       left join training_course_attended tca
            on   tca.date_attended between c.month_start and c.month_end
            and  tca.course_attended = 'Fire Safety'
group by to_char(c.month_start,'YYYY/MM')
order by 1;
```

(You could also have only the month start in the calendar table, and join on `trunc(tca.date_attended,'MONTH') = c.month_start`, though if you had indexes or partitioning on `tca.date_attended` that might be less efficient.)